# Totaling the Count of Number Of Items That Appear the Summary Page Using Indirect…

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to count the number of items that appear on the Summary Page.

All of my data is aligned on one column on the Summary Page and they all have an INDIRECT from other tabs.

I have =COUNTA(BL16:BL323), but that just gives me the resultant of 77 (I merged every 4th row).

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show some data and how it's formatted with the results you'd like?

Comment: I have asked the below question many times before… Only to get no answer… Possibly you can answer…  "I want to show you an example of my work, but I don't know how to present my work on stackoverflow. Every time I go to paste an example of my work, it comes out differently. What is the best way to paste an example of work on stackoverflow to show you what I mean? – The below is what the outcome is when I right-click and paste my information… 22-06 22-07 51 51 $6,387.92 $533,750.00 –"

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste doesn't work, please put a screenshot. You can use "Snipping Tool"or any other tool to capture the screen and only the relevant area.